# Multiple textures with displacement

Tags: texturing, procedural

I've created a sphere where I've displaced parts of the mesh using a noise texture and now want to add a separate metallic material to the displaced areas but can't seem to achieve this despite hours of trial and error. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Here's a link to the .blend file as well:

https://pasteall.org/blend/d52534ba777f445a91cf529ca8022754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ColorRamp you're using to drive your Mix Factor has too soft of a falloff (because it's set to linear). You can overcome this rather easily by using a Separate ColorRamp to the one you are using for your displacement for your Mix Factor, and setting it to *Constant*.

[image: Ramp]